# Qualtrics: reduce padding of radio button labels

Tags: css, qualtrics

I am trying to use CSS to make changes to the built-in survey theme **"Minimal 2014"**. Specifically, I am trying to reduce space in several places to make it more compact.

I have managed to reduce the space between questions and between question and answer choices using ".Skin .QuestionText" and ".Skin .QuestionBody" in the custom CSS option under Look & Feel. However, I cannot figure out how to reduce the padding / margin (?) at the **bottom of the answer choice (above the radio button), and above the next/previous buttons.** [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xgOv.jpg)

I am a CSS novice - if anyone could help, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the browser's inspector to identify the CSS rules that need to be overridden.  You can adjust these as needed:

```
.Skin #Buttons {
    margin-top: 0px; /* 50px by default */
    padding: 20px; /* 20px by default */
}

.Skin .MC .MAHR .QuestionBody table td span.LabelWrapper label,
.Skin .MC .SAHR .QuestionBody table td span.LabelWrapper label {
    padding-bottom: 5px !important; /* 20px by default */
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful! I was having trouble identifying the rules, mostly because I am not very familiar with CSS. Thanks!